# AGM Map doesn't display markers

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I am trying to use AGM (https://angular-maps.com/) in an Angular 4 app for a proof of concept, basically get a json from the api and dynamically show the locations in the AGM map.

Unfortunately the JSON from the api doesn't seem to update the map.

Do you have any ideas why ?

Thank you in advance.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public PageTitle: string = 'Location';
  public latitude: number = 50.984795;
  public longtitude: number = 8.9483832;
  public zoom: number = 7;

  public CompanyMarkers: marker[]  ;

  public localState = { value: '' };

  constructor(
    public appState: AppState,
    public title: Title,
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) {  

}

getLocations() {
  return this.http.get<marker[]>('api')
  .map(res => res);
}

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello `Home` component');

     this.getLocations().subscribe(data => {
      this.CompanyMarkers = data;
      console.log('init');
      console.log(this.CompanyMarkers);

    });

  }

}

interface marker {
CompanyAccountId?:string;
companyName?:string;
latitude?: number;
longtitude?: number;
}


<agm-map 
        [latitude]="latitude" 
        [longitude]="longtitude" 
        [zoom]="zoom"
        [disableDefaultUI]="false"
        [zoomControl]="false">

    <agm-marker 
    *ngFor="let m of CompanyMarkers;let i = index;"  
    [iconUrl]="'/assets/icon/icon-company.png'" 
    [latitude]="m.latitude" 
    [longitude]="m.longtitude">
    <agm-info-window>
        <strong>{{m.companyName}} </strong>
    </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>     
      </agm-map>
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: JSON comes back fine in the console.  Even displays values fine in a <div *ngFor="let m of CompanyMarkers" >{{m.companyName}}</div>

But I see nothing in the map.

Comment: where u are assigning value for BorrowerMarkers variable?

Comment: in public ngOnInit() , this.getLocations().subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<agm-marker 
    *ngFor="let m of CompanyMarkers;let i = index;"  
    [iconUrl]="'/assets/icon/icon-company.png'" 
    [position]="[m.latitude, m.longitude]">
    <agm-info-window>
        <strong>{{m.companyName}} </strong>
    </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```

Also check your longitude spelling

Comment: `Can't bind to 'position' since it isn't a known property of 'agm-marker'.`

Comment: transform this :     [position]="[m.latitude, m.longitude]"
 into this ->   [latitude]="[m.latitude]", [longitude]= "[m.longitude]"